# Elastic Search search query not returning when I search for synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, analyzer, synonym

So I am trying to implement synonyms (at search time) in Elastic Search, so far i've defined synonyms like this in Kibana:

```
PUT /<my_index>/_settings
{
 "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer",
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "foo => bar"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But then when I try to search for `foo` I dont get back anything.

My search request looks like this:

```
GET <my_index>/_search
{
  "size": "12",
  "from": "0",
  "min_score": "0.1",
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "product.sales_count",
            "missing": 0,
            "modifier": "log1p"
          }
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "product.image_count",
            "missing": 0,
            "modifier": "log1p"
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product.is_visible": true
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "product.i18ns.ro_RO.*.analyzed",
                "query": "foo",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "categories.i18ns.ro_RO.*.analyzed",
                "query": "foo",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "brands.i18ns.ro_RO.*.analyzed",
                "query": "foo",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "product.images.i18ns.ro_RO.*.analyzed",
                "query": "foo",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "features.i18ns.ro_RO.*.analyzed",
                "query": "foo",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "product.ref",
                "query": "foo",
                "boost": 2     
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.i18ns.ro_RO.title.raw",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I do have `bar` in my index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with the way you have defined the synonym analyzer. The `analyzer` part must come under the `analysis` part and not under the `filter` part of the index setting. Refer to this [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html), to know more about the settings of synonym token filter

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "foo => bar"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "synonym_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "bar"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "foo",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67566386",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "title": "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```